# how i can give some specific amount of spacing on console after printing a string

Tags: c++, function, coding-style, outputformat

lets just say that lenght of string is 10 than put 5 spaces on console after string , but if lenght of string is 5 than put 10 spaces on console some buid in function for this purpose in c++
lets say
string s1 , s2 and int num1 , num2 are taken from user
lets suppose s1 is maham and num1 is 20
s2 is fatima  and num2 is 30
so output should be
maham    20
fatima   30

i mean to say that spacing depend on lenght of string such that if lenght of string plus spaces equal to some specific number

the only solution came to my mid is that
let num store the total lengh lets say num=15
num2 stores lenght of string
printing string than
using a loop num-num2 imes which prints space
than print our required number or anything
but i want a solution in form of function which is build into some header file
for c++

Comment: If you open your C++ textbook to the chapter that explains formatted output using streams, and repeat the specific part that describes what `std::setw` is, how it works, and how to use it, then this should answer all of your questions.

Comment: You can use something like [`std::setw(10)`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setw) or [`std::string(10, ' ')`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string).

Answer (score 1):

You can have, from `iomanip`, the function [`std::setw()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setw) that will set the stream width parameter.

By default, the data will be put in the rightmost side. Since you want to pad from the right, i.e. write your string from the leftmost side, you could make use of [`std::left`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/left) to change the default behaviour to your liking.

You could then write the following function (example):

```
void write_and_pad(std::string_view sv, unsigned int width, bool newline = false)
{
    std::cout << std::left << std::setw(width) << sv;
    if(newline)
        std::cout << '\n';
}
```

The above function accepts a string to write, a width, and optionally a boolean to choose whether or not you want to add a newline.

<kbd>[Live example](https://godbolt.org/z/b35jdY1fx)</kbd>